# Not importing datetime mod, python behaving oddly?

Tags: python

I attempted to run this code:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
day = now.day
month = now.month
year = now.year

print(now)
print(day)
print(month)
print(year)
print(month,"/", day,"/", year) 

print(str(month) + '/'  + str(day) + '/' + str(year))


minute = now.minute
second = now.second
hour = now.hour

print(str(hour) + ':' + str(minute) + ':' + str(second))
```

When I ran it I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Anthony/Documents/datetime.py", line 1, in <module>
    from datetime import datetime
  File "/Users/Anthony/Documents/datetime.py", line 1, in <module>
    from datetime import datetime
ImportError: cannot import name 'datetime'
```

- For some odd reason, the module imports just fine from the terminal, and the code runs without problem. Only when ran from IDLE does this occur.
- There is a `__pycache__` folder in my /Documents folder, which isn't usually there. It has a file called datetime.cpython-34.pyc in it, when I attempt to open I get "File encoding is invalid for Python 3.x IDLE will convert it to UTF-8. What is the current encoding file? US-ASCII; once I click it I get "failed to decode."
- Python 3.4
- I am sure that this has to do with the problem: Attepting to delete python 3.4 completely I deinstalled it from /Applications, /Frameworks, and the .pkg files. I believe this initiated the problem. The thing is, I reinstalled it and this is still happening.

Comment: Just don't name your module as a built-in `datetime`.

Comment: @alecxe you should post that as an answer

Comment: First rule about datetime:  don't name your module datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.py` suffix files are always *importable* in python. Therefore, **you should never name your file after an existing module**. Just edit the name of your file to `dtime.py`, and everything should work fine.

If I try to create a file called `datetime.py` and I call `from datetime import datetime`, it gives the same error:

```
    from datetime import datetime
ImportError: cannot import name datetime
```

This is because it is looking for the attribute `datetime` inside your file, which doesn't exist.